# My jsp page is not showing output properly

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, el

These are my classes.

```
WebConfig.java:
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages="com.pluralsight")
public class WebConfig {

}

HelloController.java:
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;


@Controller
public class HelloController {

@RequestMapping(value="/greeting")
public String sayHallo(Model model){
    model.addAttribute("greeting", "Good morning Dhaka");

    return "hello.jsp";
}

}

WebAppInitializer.java:


public class WebAppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException      {

    WebApplicationContext context = getContext();
    servletContext.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(context));
    ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = servletContext.addServlet("DispatcherServlet", new DispatcherServlet(context));
    dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
    dispatcher.addMapping("*.html");
}

private AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext getContext() {
    AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
    context.setConfigLocation("com.pluralsight.WebConfig");

    return context;
}
```

}

This is the jsp page:
    hello.jsp:

```
<title>hello</title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>${greeting }</h2>
</body>
</html>
```

But...when I run this on server at localhost:8080/MyPage/greeting.html, then I get the output as : 
    ${greeting}

How can I solve this problem ,  means , I want to show "Good morning Dhaka!".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this `<%@ page isELIgnored="false" %>` at the top of your jsp page.

Comment: What is the secret behind this?